# How to send a Parameter while instantiate a field with a custom type inside a Class C#

Tags: c#

I hope the title was clear. I have this class

```
class PageSettings
{
     public string name { get; set; }
     public IDictionary<string,dynamic> settings { get; set; }
     // Constructor
     public PageSettings(string pageName)
     {
        name = pageName;
     }
}
```

I want to use that class inside another Class:

```
class AppSettings
{
    public PageSettings homePageSettings { get; set; }
    public PageSettings anotherPageSettings { get; set; }
}
```

Which is the correct way to do this? I *believe* this way is not correct:

```
public PageSettings homePageSettings = new PageSettings("Home");
```

I want to keep encapsulation, I am just learning C# and correct OOP. I come from a Javascript background where except for `prototype` there is no classes whatsoever.

Comment: The final statement in your question will declare a public *field* and assign it a reference to a new `PageSettings` object. Can you tell us what you *want* instead of *what you don't want*?

Comment: You can instantiate those properties in the constructor for `AppSettings`, is that what you want?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen sorry, I am still learning the correct terminology. I am not sure if the final statement is the correct way to do it, I did not say I do not want anything.

Comment: You confuse the concept Field and Property.

Comment: @David I am letting C# create the constructor for me, you say I *need* to declare the constructor if I want to instantiate the `name` properties?  So I do not need to have a constructor in `PageSettings`

Comment: @Bigeyes yes, sorry. I edited the title and added a sentence. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to initialize these properties:

```
public PageSettings homePageSettings { get; set; }
public PageSettings anotherPageSettings { get; set; }
```

You can do that in the constructor for the object which has those properties:

```
public AppSettings()
{
    homePageSettings = new PageSettings("someValue");
    anotherPageSettings = new PageSettings("anotherValue");
}
```

If you want to use values passed in to `AppSetting` instead of hard-coded ones, you can put those on the constructor as well:

```
public AppSettings(string someValue, string anotherValue)
{
    homePageSettings = new PageSettings(someValue);
    anotherPageSettings = new PageSettings(anotherValue);
}
```

Comment: It has some special meaning that you wrote `public AppSettings()` instead of `class AppSettings()` ?

Comment: @distante: What I wrote is the constructor that would go in the class.  Just like how `PageSettings` has a constructor.  It's where you would put any code you want to invoke when an instance of an object is built, such as initializing fields and properties.

Comment: Ahh! yes I understand it now, so a constructor is needed. Thank you, I am starting with C# (literally 6 days with it) and I already see I will get a lot of downvotes for dumb questions...

Comment: @distante: I wouldn't take a single down vote personally.  I get them all the time too :)